# "Android Supported Media (Encoder) Format" now includes AAC and AMR-WB, but how can we use them?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, codec

According to this page, there are some encoders available in android framework:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

I'm interested in recording audio from mic and encoding it to AAC LC/LTP and AMR-WB, but I haven't found how to in the reference page.

Any pointer would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Recently the reference page was updated:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html

.. and it says that `MediaRecorder#setAudioEncoder(int)` with `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC` and `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB` is the feature of API level 10.

So it looks like currently I have no devices to try with that. Sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful:
[Detect supported audio encoders on Android to prevent crash "The given audio encoder 2 is not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340227/detect-supported-audio-encoders-on-android-to-prevent-crash-the-given-audio-enc)
there are some devices out there with Android 4.0.x that crash when you try to use AMR even though it's listed as a core media codec.